# MacOS: strange delay between UDP/TCP packets

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, tcp, udp

I am developing an application that sends data per UDP using AsyncUDPSocket class to another client on Mac and Windows. It is very important that packets arrive instantly.

The problem is that every approx. 1000 packets I get a delay for about 2 seconds when receiving Packets. A delay of 100-200 ms would be OK, but 2 seconds produce bad user experience.

I have the UDP communication in a separate Thread, so it is little affected by user interaction with UI and such. I have already tried sending Packets faster, slower, different Packet sizes: the delay stays there. Tried using TCP instead of UDP - same result :(

It does not seem to happen on Windows Cliets. 
Maybe there is some system buffer in MacOS that needs to be flushed every time it hast N packets or N bytes of data??? 
Has anyone an idea how can I prevent the delay from happening?

Comment: Check your DNS set-up. If you connect by hostname, the delay might be caused by name resolution.

Comment: I connect using an IP address, so no DNS lookups are needed

Comment: Just in case there _is_ DNS involved, add the IP address of peer A in /etc/hosts  on peer B (the one experiencing the delay) and see if there's a difference.

Comment: Any success in solving this problem? I see the same effect with a Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things that can slow down a network program temporarily, it's hard to know where to start.  Have you tried this on multiple networks?  Both wireless and ethernet networks?  What kind of switch do you have?  Does this happen on different OS X computers, or just on one?  Can you reproduce the delay with a simpler command line program?  Are you using garbage collection?  (Grasping at straws here...)

Just out of curiosity, I tested the roundtrip time on UDP echo packets sent from my Mac to another computer on the same LAN.  Out of over 60,000 UDP packets with a 1,000 byte payload, none of them took longer than 32 ms, the mean round trip was 0.6 ms, and the sample deviation was 0.21.

(I'm also curious what you need such low latency for.)

Comment: I have tried it on wireless and Ethernet networks using different computers. All computers are connected using a router (tried multiple routers as well). I am not using garbage collection, but I'll recheck if I have forgotten to disable it. I could reproduce this delay with a simple app, but not a command line one (will try this as well). The data sent between the clients is actually mouse movement, so I need low latency to make those mouse movements smooth...

Comment: @Nostradamus: Try netcat from http://netcat.sourceforge.net/ for command line testing. It's worth having in your toolbox. Also, look at your thread's scheduling policy.

Comment: Thx for the info, I'll try netcat. The thread runs on normal priority and the delay also happens when I disable any communication with the main thread, timers and so on. Maybe it's a problem with AsyncUDPSocket???

Comment: Is there perhaps a send queue you are overstuffing? In Linux, (which you are not working on but I am more familiar with) there are some tunables that influence the size of UDP send/receive queues. Worth a shot ... Also, look into coalescing some of these mouse events.